# pointer (ref to structure) as an argument for a function to assign value

Tags: c++, pointers, structure, arguments, assign

I am a newbie in programming and apologise in advance if my question is too silly.

My c++ project is compiled as library .xll (DLL for excel), the framework code (program entry point) is coded correct and work stable. Custom functions are separate modules.

```
// header.h
typedef struct _TMDYDate {
    long month;
    long day;
    long year;
} TMonthDayYear;
```

the file `funcs.c` has a function:

```
// funcs.c
#include "header.h"

__declspec(dllexport) long GetDate() {
    TMonthDayYear myDate;
    myDate.day = 1 ;
    myDate.month = 1;
    myDate.year = 2000;

    if (DateToMDY(2004, &myDate) != 1) {
        return 0;
    }

    return myDate.year;
}
```

where the function `DateToMDY` is declared in separate file `Dates.c`:

```
// dates.c

int DateToMDY (long tmpyear, TMonthDayYear *mdy) {
    mdy->year = tmpyear; // <- Error is here
    return 1;
}
```

I debug a function `GetDate()` and get an error when try to assign by reference (`mdy->year = tmpyear;`) the value 2004.

The error is:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x0e342b84 (alcDates.xll) in EXCEL.EXE: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x40e3db28
```

The funny thing is when i move declaration of `DateToMDY` to the file `funcs.c`, the same where the `DateToMDY` is called - there is no error.

I assume it is to wrong memory usage, but for me is critical to isolate functionality in different modules (ex. dates.c, array.c, sorting.c ...).

I don't know where to look for, may be i have wrong project compilation settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you call the function from a place where its declaration isn't visible. If you do, the compile does not know what types the parameters should have so it passes them all as ints.

Functions called from another .c file should be declared in the corresponding .h file,and included in all .c files using the function.

Comment: I think its not possible to call function from that place where function declaration is not visible. Such code cant be compiled

Comment: @Anton: You can actually, if you use old C language rules. Initially you did't have to declare parameters or return values, as long as they were all of type int. If you run your C compiler in permissive mode, that still works.

Comment: Its very interesting I didnt know about such possibilities

Comment: If instead of struct type i pass vanilla types like long or double - the function from another .c file works correct